# How can I change the color of the road in Google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-canvas

I'm looking for a way to change the color of roads (yellow) in MapView for Android. I thought of overriding the `onDraw` method, and then to go over each pixel and change it, but the method is final.

I also thought of wrapping the MapView with a ViewGroup and then try overriding its onDraw, but I'm not sure of how to do it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Now (I'm don't know from what exactly moment, seems from Google Maps API V3.0) its easy with [Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling) feature of Maps Android API. For map style JSON preparing you can use [Styling Withard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). Also you can add only necessary parts to JSON style object, not for all map elements. For example for yellow roads (with blue labels) JSON (`/res/raw/map_style.json`) can be:

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffff00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#0000ff"
      }
    ]
  }
```

]

and `MainActyvity.java` with map Fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.map_style));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }
        // Position the map's camera near Sydney, Australia.
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(50.4501,30.5234), 16.0f));

    }

}
```

and `activity_main.xls`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.just.googlemapsgeneral.activities.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As a result you should got:

[image: Android styled map fragment]

You can also add style parameters for static map:
for

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&key=[your_MAPS_API_KEY]&center=50.4501,30.5234&zoom=16&size=640x640&style=feature:road|element:geometry|color:0xFFFF00

request you got:

[image: Styled static map]

Please see [Official Blog](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/09/custom-map-styling-with-google-maps.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you consider making the switch to [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) using OpenStreetMap data instead of Google MapView and modify the source code for street color rendering.